# Why is my Lua if-else not working properly?

Tags: if-statement, lua

```
print("Type a number:")
firstNum = io.read()
print("Type another number:")
secondNum = io.read()
print("First: " .. firstNum .. "\nSecond: " .. secondNum)
if firstNum > secondNum then
  print("first is bigger than second")
elseif firstNum < secondNum then
  print("first is less than second")
else
  print("first is equal to second")
end
```

Input:
firstNum = 5
secondNum = 15
Output:
first is bigger than second
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firstNum` and `secondNum` are strings, and `"5"` lexicographically comes *after* `"15"` because it starts by comparing the first characters *only*: `'5'` > `'1'`.

You need to convert them to numbers before comparing.

```lua
print("Type a number:")
firstNum = tonumber(io.read())
print("Type another number:")
secondNum = tonumber(io.read())
if firstNum > secondNum then
  print("first is bigger than second")
elseif firstNum < secondNum then
  print("first is less than second")
else
  print("first is equal to second")
end
```

This prints the expected `first is less than second`.

Comment: don't forget to handle unwanted input!